# unable to get the return value thru xcom push

Tags: python, shell, airflow

With help of sh operator i am pushing a value thru xcom and trying to pull and assign it to a get_master_ip variable. But it is not returning the value, it is printing {{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='tnew', key='return_value') }}. I want to see the output as 172.20.1.1 . Please help

```
cluster_command = """
echo 172.20.1.1 """

tnew = BashOperator(
      task_id ='tnew',
      bash_command =cluster_command,
      xcom_push=True,
      dag =dag, )

get_master_ip = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='tnew', key='return_value') }}"
```

Comment: You need to pull the XCom value with another task

Comment: when i am trying to print the get_master_ip it is printing the "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='tnew', key='return_value') }}"  rather than the value in it.. If i pull the xcom in another task also. It is printing the "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='tnew', key='return_value') }}" .. I want the value in it.

Comment: Can you try pulling the xcom value in a PythonOperator with `provide_context=True`?